# Integrate Compass with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: rubygems, visual-studio-2013, compass-sass

Has anyone managed to integrate Compass with VS2013? How did you do?
I tried to follow a tutorial for VS 2012. 
But the external commands do not react when I'm trying to make a compass project for a mvc4 project.

This is the tutorial i followed.
[Integrate Compass with VS 2012 tutorial](http://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/integrating-the-compass-css-framework-into-visual-studio/)

Comment: I used Mindscape Web Workbench to use Compass in VS2012. After seeing that Microsoft added SASS support to VS2013, I was hoping not to need to install it again. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably already answered your question now, but for anyone else looking, I struggled with this but found it was much easier than I was thinking.

1. Download the whole [Compass zip](https://github.com/Compass/compass/) from github
2. Unzip the download, and then navigate from the top folder through to `/core/stylesheets/` and just copy the folder `compass` and the file `_compass.scss` into your project folder structure, into the same folder that your other SASS files will sit in.
3. In your .scss files, just add an import right at the top: `@import "compass";`

If you need a compiler as well, then the best one I found was [Web Essentials for VS 2013 Update 4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361). In my solution, I had to restart VS after adding compass, and change all the files from `read only` to `read/write` so that Web Essentials could access them all.

**TIP:** If you look in `Tools > Options > Web Essential 2013 > Sass` and make it use Ruby to compile, then you get useful error messaging with line numbers when you hit a compiler error (although it is more prone to crashes!).

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that it's much easier to use [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) which allows you to build Style Bundles based on SCSS, SASS, LESS, CoffeeScript the whole shebang. Given that Compass uses SCSS mixins, I suspect you can merge these with your styles.

Comment: Compass is a compiler and a set of mixins for scss and sass files as far as I can tell. By linking them into BundleTrandsformer in your web.config you can have the best of both ASP.NET and Compass for your web development.